# Is there a way to set different transitions for different transformations?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

In this project, there's an image that needs to scale with a transition when hovered over, but it also is translated first. The only problem is, the transition is applied to both transformations.

The properties for the image are:

```
.gal_img{
    width: 60%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    transform: translate(30%);
    transition: all 0.1s, border 0s, width 0s;
}
```

The properties for the image on hover are:

```
.gal_img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Not yet, its currently not possible to split transforms....but it's coming.

Comment: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5705698193178624#:~:text=Feature%3A%20Independent%20Properties%20for%20CSS,property%20interact%20with%20each%20other.

Comment: When the img is hovered, I can see you want to scale it but do you want it to remain translated?

Comment: keep the translation on the hover `transform:transform(30%) scale(1.1);`